# Difference between two dates excluding weekends and given list of holidays in R

Tags: r

I want to calculate the number of days between 2 dates excluding weekends and the given list of holidays

```
a <- c('2016/05/2')
b <- c('2016/05/11')
a <- as.Date(a,'%Y/%m/%d')
b <- as.Date(b,'%Y/%m/%d')

Nweekdays <- Vectorize(function(a, b) 
                         sum(!weekdays(seq(a, b, "days")) %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday")))
Nweekdays(a, b)
```

This is how I can calculate the number of days without the weekends. However, suppose I want to exclude a list of given holidays which is on '2016/05/3' and '2016/05/4' and then calculate the number of days between the mentioned two dates (excluding the weekends). I am unable to write this code. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
f <- function(a, b, h) { 
  d <- seq(a, b, 1)[-1]   
  sum(!format(d, "%u") %in% c("6", "7") & !d %in% h)
}
f(a, b, as.Date(c("2016/05/3", "2016/05/4"),'%Y/%m/%d'))
```

or, with a data frame:

```
vf <- Vectorize(f, c("a", "b"))
df <- data.frame(a=rep(a, 2), b=rep(b, 2))
df$diff <- with(df, vf(a, b, as.Date(c("2016/05/3", "2016/05/4"),'%Y/%m/%d')) )
```

Comment: Just one more simple question...how do I use it on a data frame? When ever I am trying to use it on a data frame I am getting an error. Could you please help me to apply it on a data frame.

Comment: What happens if i want the dates to be state specific? I currently have a data frame with rowbined holiday dates for each state (i.e. row1: 1/1/2018 | State1, row2: 1/1/2018 | state2

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as following,

```
holidays <- as.Date(c('2016/05/3' , '2016/05/4' ))
date_range <- seq.Date(a, b, 1)

date_range[!weekdays(date_range) %in% (c("Saturday", "Sunday")) & !date_range %in% holidays]

#[1] "2016-05-02" "2016-05-05" "2016-05-06" "2016-05-09" "2016-05-10" "2016-05-11"
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak!! This one works absolutely fine too!! Thanks for sharing a different approach to solve the problem.

Comment: Just one more simple question...how do I use it on a data frame? When ever I am trying to use it on a data frame I am getting an error. Could you please help me to apply it on a data frame.

Comment: @shejomamu could you update the question with an example?