# R: Difference between two dates excluding weekends and given list of holidays specific to state

Tags: r, date, datetime, weekend

Extending this question from this post

[Difference between two dates excluding weekends and given list of holidays in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37068210/difference-between-two-dates-excluding-weekends-and-given-list-of-holidays-in-r)

What if i have holidays specific to states. How do i incorporate holidays by state?

```
holiday <- data.frame(h = as.Date(c("2016/05/3", "2016/05/3"),'%Y/%m/%d'), 
                      s = c('state1','state2'),
                      stringsAsFactors=FALSE
                      )

d <- data.frame(d1 = as.Date(c('2016/05/2','2016/05/2'),'%Y/%m/%d'),
                d2= as.Date(c('2016/05/10','2016/05/10'),'%Y/%m/%d'),
                s = c('state1','state3'),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

produces

```
> d
          d1         d2      s
1 2016-05-02 2016-05-10 state1
2 2016-05-02 2016-05-10 state3
> holiday
           h      s
1 2016-05-03 state1
2 2016-05-03 state2
```

The solution offered in the link is holiday specific to dates, but doesn't take into account the states. How can i incorporate the state.

Desired state is an extra column in d which calculates the days excluding weekends and holidays specific to states

Comment: Please share code to create your data, as well as what your desired output is.  It will be much easier for us to help you if you do so.

Comment: hope the changes helps. tq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an inelegant solution to my question. hope you find this useful.

```
library('dplyr')

holiday <- data.frame(h = as.Date(c("2016/05/3", "2016/05/3"),'%Y/%m/%d'), 
                      s = c('state1','state2'),
                      stringsAsFactors=FALSE
                      )

d <- data.frame(d1 = as.Date(c('2016/05/2','2016/05/2'),'%Y/%m/%d'),
                d2= as.Date(c('2016/05/10','2016/05/10'),'%Y/%m/%d'),
                s = c('state1','state3'),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

state <- as.character(unique(d$s))

#function to exclude weekends and holidays
f <- function(a, b, h) { 
  d <- seq(a, b, 1)[-1]   
  sum(!format(d, "%u") %in% c("6", "7") & !d %in% h)
}
vf <- Vectorize(f, c("a", "b"))

#Function to calculate days excluding weekends and holidays by state
#state is done iteratively
datalist = list()
for (i in 1:length(state)) {
  # ... make some data

  #extract holidays by state as vectors
  holi <- holiday %>% 
    filter(s== state[i]) %>%
    select(h) %>%
    pull()

  #create new data by state
  dat <- d %>%
    filter(s == state[i])
  dat$diff <- with(dat,vf(d1, d2, holi))

  datalist[[i]] <- dat # add it to your list
  rm('dat')
}

new_df = dplyr::bind_rows(datalist)
```

Differentiating holidays by specific to states and excluding the weekends

```
          d1         d2      s diff
1 2016-05-02 2016-05-10 state1    5
2 2016-05-02 2016-05-10 state3    6
```