# Exclude weekdays while subtracting the dates

Tags: r

Is there a way to exclude weekends while taking a difference between dates

```
as.Date("2021-02-02") - as.Date("2021-01-25")
Time difference of 8 days
```

Expected output (Since there are 2 days that are weekends and needs to be exlcuded

```
Time difference of 6 days
```

Comment: I think you are looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37068210/difference-between-two-dates-excluding-weekends-and-given-list-of-holidays-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a sequence between two days, exclude weekends and count the days.

```
s1 <- as.Date("2021-02-02") 
s2 <- as.Date("2021-01-25")
sum(!format(seq(s2, s1, 'day'), '%u') %in% 6:7) - 1
#[1] 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work, creating a function.

```
daysdiff <- function(date1, date2){
  sum(!weekdays(seq( as.Date(date1), as.Date(date2), 'days')) %in% c('Sunday','Saturday')) - 1
}
daysdiff("2021-01-25", "2021-02-02")
[1] 6
```